# Compile error on asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple asp.net webform page which i use to display page related data based on pageID.

I am trying to define page level variable so that i can access there variable in different function used in this page. But i am getting few error. for example if my code is like

```
    public partial class PageHome : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            int _LangID = 1;
            _LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
            int _PageID = 0;
            int _PID = Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx");


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int _LanguageID = _LangID;
        GetPageDetails(_PageID);
    }   

}
```

Then i get

```
Error message:
Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration (_LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));)
Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  (_LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));)
Method must have a return type  
Identifier expected
```

and if i try to use define these variable inside constructor

```
//public PageHome()
//{
    //int _LangID = 1;
    //_LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
    //int _PageID = 0;
    //int _PID = Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx");
//}
```

Then I get different errors like

`The name '_LangID' does not exist in the current context`
`The name '_PageID ' does not exist in the current context`

What is the best way to define page level variable which are defined once and access in different function

**Update**:
`Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En")` and `Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx")` functions are defined in a seperate class file under kept under `App_Code/Helper/Helper.cs`

**Update Two**: Working code based on `JonSKeet` answer.

```
public partial class PageHome : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            int _LangID = 1;
            _LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
            int _PageID = 0;
    public PageHome()
    {
            int _PID = Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx");
}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int _LanguageID = _LangID;
        GetPageDetails(_PageID);
    }   

}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me - did you expect your `Page_Load` method to be part of your `PageHome` class? Because it's not at the moment...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Just updated my code as i had closed class after defining varibale by mistake in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just have a statement like:

```
_LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
```

within a class declaration. It would have to be in a method, or constructor, or something like that.

However, given that you've just declared the variable, you could simply change these two lines:

```
int _LangID = 1;
_LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
```

... to one:

```
int _LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
```

However, you'll then have an error here:

```
int _PID = Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx");
```

as you can't refer to one instance field within the initializer for another. That initialization would have to happen in the constructor... in which case I'd suggest doing *both* of them in the constructor, for clarity:

```
public class PageHome : Page
{
    // Do you really not need to initialize this to something else?
    int _PageID = 0;
    int _LangID;
    int _PID;

    public PageHome()
    {
        _LangID = int.Parse(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
        _PID = Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx");
    }

    ...
}
```

On the other hand, do those values *actually* change on a per-page-instance basis? Perhaps they should actually be static fields? (It's hard to tell what the bigger picture is here.)

Comment: Even if i do it like you have mentioned then i get error for `int _PID = Helper.GetPageID(_LangID, "Home.aspx");` this line as `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'PageHome._LangID'`

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: Right, you'd need to put *that* one into the constructor. Will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure i would sugest tryparsing the int from the appsettings
You could make some sort of tryparse methode in witch you can get the appsettings. This way there wont be an error if the settings are missing and the int will have a null value.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
int? _LangID = TryParse2(Helper.GetAppSetting("LangID_En"));
}
int? TryParse2(string s) {
    int i;
    if (!int.TryParse(s, out i)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Also does your class helper get the app settings the corect way? I personaly use somthing like

```
var debugSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsDebug"];
```